# web app pattern for forcing re-login without losing changes? (without saving drafts)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, authentication, forms-authentication

Today, our B2B web application times out user sessions after 6 hours of inactivity. If a user's session times out, the user is redirected to the login page, and then redirected back to the original destination after login (via a "returnURL" querystring parameter sent to the login page).

This works great for regular HTTP GET requests. But what if a user is in the middle of a long data-entry operation and then goes home for the night?  If the user tries to submit the form the next morning, their changes are lost.

Instead, I'd like to enable a similar workflow for forms like we currently have for GET requests: the user clicks "save", the user is forced to re-authenticate, and (if login succeeds) then the form would be submitted. Another alternative would be to force a re-login, but instead of submitting the form, simply drop the user on the original page so that the user could try again to save changes.

All the data we need to submit is on the client-- it's not like we're storing data in the session that would have been lost.

Is there an accepted pattern to handle this case?  Should I use a window.open popup window and close it after successful login?  Use a jquery dialog overlaid on the page?  Something else?

I know that login UI is often treated specially by web apps to reduce cross-site scripting risk and for other security-related reasons, so wasn't sure if there was a well-known best practice for this use-case.

One way to handle this would be to periodically save drafts of the user's work, like StackOverflow does. For cost reasons that's not practical in our case-- for now we simply want to make saving-changes workflows resilient to session expiration.

We're using ASP.NET MVC on the back-end if it matters, and jQuery on the front end, but my question is really more about security and programming best practices that I'd expect to be platform-neutral.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the amount of data being collected, but a possible solution could be to save the page state to the browser's local storage using either "localStorage" or "sessionStorage". "localStorage" and "sessionStorage" are properties of the web browser that are exposed in Javascript and are supported in most modern browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE 9+). "localStorage" holds data indefinitely while "sessionStorage" holds data until the browser or current tab is closed.

It may be possible to store everything needed about the page, redirect the user to log in, and then reload the page using the stored data.

Before redirecting to login:

```
if (window.sessionStorage) {
   window.sessionStorage.setItem("firstName", $("#firstNameField").text());
   window.sessionStorage.setItem("lastName", $("#lastNameField").text());
}
```

After retunring from login:

```
   if (window.sessionStorage) {
      $("#firstName").text(sessionStorage.getItem("firstName"));
      $("#lastName").text(sessionStorage.getItem("lastName"));
   }
```

Comment: I was hoping for a more lightweight solution, e.g. have the client verify that the user is logged in before submitting the form. Having to persist local form data seems much harder.